# using java select city and country from a given string that contains full address

Tags: java, string, location

I am writing a code in which I want user to provide a string of unknown length.. suppose he provided a string.. now I want to get city and country present in that string...
If anybody have any better idea, please share..

Comment: post your code, your input String and your Output String.. Only then can we help..

Comment: _"If anybody have any better idea"_ What's yours? Could you show us please?

Comment: "get city and country present in that string" what exactly is that ?? What have u tried ?

Comment: I did not write any code yet.. what I am thinking is that I will provide a string like "my name is Ankit Kumar. I dwell in a locality of bangalore. And my address is #30, XYZ apartment, 3rd cross, 5th main road, Banashankari layout, Bangalore, India."  .... so from given string i want to get city ="Bangalore" and Country = "India".. I can extract by pattern matching but If address will be changed of some other city than how I will extract... basic concept is that I will give different strings with different address.. now I dont know how to get city and country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement, you have to build a case where you need to defined all the possibility city or country like Array city= new Array["America","England","China","Myanmar"]; after that now loop your array then read the user defined line from index 0 and each time move your character point +1(do in a loop too)(convert it in String) then search your city pattern to match with the character(String). Your program complexity will increase more and more due to your requirement, I think your complexity will raise up to O(n*n), it is not good for memory.
On my view of point, you should ask from user to get the actual requirement step by step like (Enter City :**_ then Enter Country :__**) it is better to handle the string.GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Thank You soewin.. but it is not like that.. actually all the strings are pre-available in a file, so cant ask anybody to enter city and country manually.. program should read all available strings one by one and should get city and country from those strings.. And In order to make an Array its kind of impossible to make an Array which can have names of all cities of the world.. I think there are around 300 countries in the world.. so array of all countries is somehow possible but in case of cities its impossible..
is there any way to use Google API or some other to do this task?

Comment: Is it possible to find only countries by using any class or API available??

Answer (score 0):

In the question you never specified the format of the input string but assuming the format is "city, country" then this works

```
String s = "the name of a city, the name of a country";
String city = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(", "));
String country = s.substring(s.indexOf(", ") + 2);
System.out.println("City = " + city);
System.out.println("Country = " + country);
```

Comment: Thanks codewiz :)
but how it will pic from string s = "my address is #30, XYZ apartment, 3rd cross, 5th main road, Banashankari layout, Bangalore, India."

Comment: Actually city may come at any position.. means it may like in above comment of mine.

Comment: If there is no specified format, you would need to input a list of all valid cities and check if any of them are found anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your questions are very interesting. The program you are writing now is depending on LOGIC and I think there is no such jar files available to get solution on it. It is better to get solution manually. Did you ever think about Dictionary program. Mostly Dictionary words are written in a text file and at run time, the program load that words into an array or some other Collections. This way you can also Load Your file at runtime into a 2D array or collection(mostly HashMap is used). So you can scan your file and load it.Suppose u want to read 
Example:

Agra,India

London,England

Yangon,Myanmar

Tokyo,Japan

etc...

`    String line;

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(dataFile);

//dataFile is your file directory

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 

HashMap<String,String> divideCityCountry =new HashMap<String,String>();

while((line=br.readLine())!=-1)

{

String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");//use the ',' as delimiter 

divideCityCountry.put(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1]);

} `
```

Now you can check or get the city and country in the divideCityCountry HashMap().
Hope this may helpful.Good Luck!